# Error: '.class' expected or cannot find symbol method

Tags: java

I can't figure out what exactly is wrong. This is what i get when i compile this program:

```
cannot find symbol method kuce(java.util.List<java.lang.String>,java.lang.String[]).
```

If i change this row:

```
System.out.print(mauka.kuce(mauka,temp));
```

to

```
System.out.print(mauka.kuce(mauka,temp[]));
```

then i get  this:

```
'.class' expected
```

Here is the full code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class metodes
{
    String p="";

    public String kuce(List x, String c[]) {
        for (int v=0; v < x.size(); v++) p = p +c[v] ;
        return p;
    }
}

public class ShowFile 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int i;
        FileInputStream fin;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(" Fails nav atrasts");
            return;
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println(" Ievadiet: ShowFile faila_vards");
            return;
        }

        StringBuffer ab = new StringBuffer();
        String a="";
        String temp[];
        do {
            i = fin.read();
            if (i!=-1) a= a + ((char) i);
        } while(i != -1);

        a = a.replace("\r\n", " ");
        temp = a.split("\\.");
        String h = ".";
        for (int o = 0; o < temp.length; o++) {temp[o] = temp[o] + h;}

        List<String> mauka = Arrays.asList(temp);
        System.out.print(mauka.kuce(mauka,temp));
        fin.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your program's indentation before asking for help with it. As currently written, it's very hard to read.

Comment: Should be fixed if the edit is accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kuce()` is a method on the class `metodes`.  You're trying to call it on class `List<String>`, as that's what the variable `mauka` is declared as.  You need to make an instance of `metodes` and then you can call `kuce()` on that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem reported by compiler means that it is unable to find `kuce()` with the List interface of Collections.

`kuce()` method has been defined in `metodes` class and only can be used with the objects of metode . You are trying to call `kuce()` on List interface .

could you please change your code to create and object of `metodes` and then call kuce() on it.